# Send data from php to python and back

Tags: php, python

I have been searching for a while in how to successfully `exec` a Python script through PHP, just for a test thats all.

I've never actually worked with Python and a while since I programmed in PHP but looked for a simple code to send data from PHP to Python and then in `.py` send back data to PHP.

I have tried `exec` in PHP, with and without json enc/dec without any success.

These are the commands that have I tried in PHP:

```
* $result = shell_exec('pythontest.py' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));
* exec("python pythontest.py", $resultData);
  var_dump($resultData);
```

with no success.

In `pythontest.py`: a print to send back data.

Tried with full paths of both Python and `pythontest.py` (PHP).

enc/dec with json works in PHP file so nothing seems to be wrong in the PHP code still I can't run the script!

As I said, I haven't worked with Python before so I wonder if there is more needed than just writing the code in the script in order to make it work?

I have seen many posts about this and tried their code that "would work for them" but not for me^^

Additional info: PHP through WAMP, .py in same map. It is supposed to be web based, if that makes it difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [executing python script from php under windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545239/executing-python-script-from-php-under-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the directory containing `python.exe` is in the PATH of your PHP script (via `getenv('PATH')`).

Try running `python c:\path\to\pythontest.py` directly via a Windows command prompt. Does that work? If not, debug PATHs and issues from there, then try again in PHP.

If your WAMP stack runs PHP with limited permissions, check to make sure that user has "Read and execute" type permissions on the `python.exe` file, *as well as the entire directory which contains it, recursively.* This might be overkill, but recursively setting perms for that user on the whole python distribution directory rules out permissions-related problems.

Try qualifying the python executable's name with `.exe`, e.g. `c:\python27\python.exe pythontest.py` (you might have tried that anyway, since you say you tried with "full paths", but I'm throwing it out there to make sure you included the `.exe`).

Try replacing the contents of `pythontest.py` with something extremely simple (e.g. `print 'hello'`) and check whether or not behavior changes.

Also, please post the contents (or at least first lines) of `pythontest.py`.

Comment: i have tried change path with setenv, full code for the test is under your answer, first the path was system32 and i changed it to the python.exe folder with setenv, checked with getenv and it showed the new path.
in my .py file i have now print("hello") and can exec it through cmd but still not php!
i have checked with permissions for the folder/files and every user can read and execute, also added "Everyone" with full rights jsut to be sure.
have i done something wrong with permission, python code or paths?

Comment: Hmm. Any chance you've got those functions disabled in WAMP? (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/). What happens when you try to run normal system commands (e.g. "dir")?

Comment: Looked over .ini and nothing is disabled and dir commands works.

Comment: Could you post or link to your `php.ini`?

Comment: I'm unable to access that due to my corporate firewall. I'll try to take a look at it when I'm home. Try setting your safe_mode related settings to the most promiscuous possible values: it's not something you should ever do in production, but it might help isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have now tried changing the path, as `python.exe` was not in the same directory. 
My end result on this was

`$output = getenv('PATH');`
`echo "Real Path: " . $output . "<br>";`
`$ret = apache_getenv("PATH");`
`echo "Apache Path: " . $ret . "<br>";`
`apache_setenv("PATH", "C:/Python33");`
`$ret = apache_getenv("PATH");`
`echo "Apache new path: " . $ret . "<br>";`
`$output = getenv('PATH');`
`echo "Real path, hopefully changed: " . $output . "<br>";`

this was just to see if i could change the path, since i have never done that before.
i have now only

`import sys, json`
 `print ("hello")`

in my python file and tried to run it through cmd, and it worked.
but when i try run it with php, it fails once again.
i have also looked over the permissions:
admin, user have permission to read and execute, i even added "Everyone" with full permission on folder and sub-folder/files just to see if that made any difference.
something i have missed or did i do something wrong with permission, python code or paths ?